# How to check if value is correct for key in HashMap in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, hashmap

I'm writing a simple GUI program where I have to input login and password for user and then check if he is in database (my Hashmap). That's where i have problem. I checked if login is correct by containsKey and checked for password by containsValue. The problem is, that if in example I have 2 users:

```
login: user1 password: example
login: user2 password: programing
```

If I put login as `user1` in my `JTextField` and password "programing", the program says, that it's correct.

That's where I have a problem. How to check the password for exact login, which is key?

Would be very thankful for any clues or solutions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a check like this:

```
 if(userEnteredPassword.equals(hashMap.get(userEnteredUsername))){
     // Correct credentials.
     .....
 }
```

It's important to use `userEnteredPassword.equals....` instead of `hashMap.get(userEnteredUsername).equals...` because you'll get a null pointer exception if there is no map entry for `userEnteredUsername`

Comment: ...or use the `Objects.equals` method.

Comment: It really helped alot. Thank's for your feedback :)

Comment: @PawełGustawKolasiński I'm glad I could help. Good luck.

Comment: but what if 2 users have the same password? Then with this method I get message, that the password is wrong.

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to write 1 thing in if(), now everything works perfectly :)

Comment: @PawełGustawKolasiński What this does is to compare the password entered by the user to the password mapped to the user entered username in the hash map. Having multiple users with the same password shouldn't cause any conflicts.